# Creating a literal symbol in a macro

Tags: scala, scala-macros

`Context` has methods `literal(Int)`, `literal(String)`, etc. How can I create a literal symbol given the name (i.e. `'name`)? There is an obvious workaround: create `Symbol.apply(literal(name))` instead, but I expect there should be a direct method as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `q"'sym"` too obvious?

```
c.Expr[Any](q"'mysym")
```

By obvious, I mean, sorry if this is obviously not what you mean.

Less conveniently,

```
c.Expr[Any](c.parse("'asym"))

c.Expr[Any](c.parse(s"'$name"))
```

or maybe painfully,

```
c.Expr[Any](Apply(c.typeOf[scala.Symbol].typeSymbol, c.literal("mysym").tree))
```

Comment: It should have been, but it wasn't. Except name is a variable, so `q"'$name"`. However, how does it look without using macro paradise?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I think as edited. It's really hard going back from qq.

Answer (score 1):

In soon to be realeased 2.11 you'll be able to just unquote symbol into a quasiquote to get a correct tree without hassle:

```
val s: scala.Symbol = 'foo
q"$s" // q"'foo"
```

This should work in 2.10 with [macro paradise plugin](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/paradise.html) as well.